# multiple ht access rules in one file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-routing

My site should attempt to serve all requests from a cache subdirectory (/app/storage/cache) such that a request for /two.html is served from /app/storage/cache/two.html

More examples:
/ served from /app/storage/cache/index.html
/two.html served from /app/storage/cache/two.html
/folder served from /app/storage/cache/folder/index.html

If no files/directories are found it should handle all requests with a php file /app/router.php

What I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/storage/www/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /app/storage/www/$1 [L]
```

that works fine for catching all urls and serving the correct resource without changing the url. Now to catch all else:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . app/router.php [L]
```

That also works, but then the first set of conditions no longer works...

Comment: Is there a reason why router.php cannot check if there is a file in the cache already? It certainly is possible to do this with .htaccess, but it is usually wise to refresh the cache every so often, even if you think nothing has changed. Think about a situation where an incomplete file has been written to cache, or a resource was unavailable, and the wrong thing has been cached. With the .htaccess approach, such a cached file would stay around.... forever. Via router.php you can force to replace the cache once in a while.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes, because I want the site to be served statically for speed gains. The router just catches admin routes for CMS editing of the site, which then writes to the cache. 'Cache' is a misnomer in this case, as the site is always served from there, while the dynamic part of the site (php) acts as a site generator. If you could share how to achieve what I want with an .htaccess it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways I can think of how to go about this. One is check the cache via router.php before generating the page through that same file. The other two ways involve some rewrite-magic.

I have not tested either of these.

#### Fall-through approach

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/storage/www/$1

#From this point on, the file/dir either exists or
#%{REQUEST_FILENAME} is now /app/storage/www/something
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/storage/www/ /app/router.php [L]
```

#### Explicit test

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/storage/www/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/storage/www/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/router.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/storage/www/$1 [L]
```

Both approaches can likely be sped up by using Apache's main configuration file (httpd.conf) instead of the .htaccess file, as it does not need to search for/read the .htaccess file on every request.

Comment: Static requests are served okay (from /app/storage/www) but other requests don't go to /app/router.php, any ideas? (that was the fall through approach, explicit test handles everything by the router...)

Comment: I am not sure why the first one doesn't work; I would need to test that, but I can't for at least some time. For the second one I made a silly mistake (I matched against `^`, but used `$1` in the condition. Changing the matching part to `^(.*)$` should fix that. You might need to turn of path info with `AcceptPathInfo Off`.

Comment: Okay I've made that change, it works a little but not on all conditions, I've updated my question with the other two urls (route home and a folder) to show what I'm testing against.

Comment: I think that adding another condition to the first part will fix that. `DirectoryIndex` will take care of the rest.

Comment: Okay fantastic! It would be great if you could just add a note as to the difference between the fall through approach and explicit test, I'm not sure I understand 100%

Comment: The main difference is the amount of subrequests it does. Each `!-f` and `!-d` does a subrequest to check if a file exists. This costs time. Ideally we do the least amount of them. For this reason it is better to do rewriterules in httpd.conf instead of .htaccess too, as rules are only loaded on Apache startup and not on every request, which saves time.